# box2d - How do I render lights in a proper way?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, light

Can you modify the darkness you get on screen when using a ray handler in libgdx with box2d world? Also when I put lights over sprites they look different because the light is on top of them. Can you render lights so that the color of the sprite is the same, even though it is lighted up by a source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can modify the darkness by setting ambient light. For instance:

```
rayHandler.setAmbientLight(0.5f);
```

makes everything 50% brighter.

Also, if you find that the lights over your sprites cause too much of a difference in colour, you might want to set the light's colour to white and set the alpha lower (just tweak around with it until you think it looks good).